# Deleted my SharePoint files in directory - Placed it back and now site not working

Tags: iis, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I am working with SharePoint 2007

My SharePoint site files are located here............

> C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\22544

I deleted the folder 22544 by mistake but placed the folder back after i realized what I did and now my SharePoint site is not working at all.

I did a IISRESET and nothing helped. Getting error........

> An error occurred loading a configuration file: Failed to start monitoring changes to 'C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\22544\web.config' because access is denied

```
Source Error:
[No relevant source lines]
```

What have i done and how can i fixed this?

Answer (score 3):

Check the permissions of the folder. Perhaps you did not restore the NTFS permissions

Comment: Where must I check for this?? In IIS?

Comment: Hi, any idea on how and where I must go for this?